# I've added lots of lines to github project, why does it say I only added two?

Tags: github

Have a look at the contributors page for this project:

https://github.com/Sahand1993/CraigslistPrice/graphs/contributors?from=2018-04-22&to=2018-05-14&type=a

My username is Sahand1993. If you look at my graph, it says I've only added **2 lines of code**. But if you look at the project file called `elasticsearch/searcher.py`, you'll see that I added that entire file, which is around 200 lines long!

So, why is Github saying I've only added 2 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub matches commits to users [via the email address in the commit](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/). You haven't set your email address properly.

I see several commits from `sahandzarrinkoub@n157-p198.eduroam.kth.se` and `sahandzarrinkoub@Sahands-MBP.lan`, but only one from `sahandz@hotmail.com`. This last email address is [the one you've registered with GitHub](https://github.com/Sahand1993).

If the other email addresses are real email addresses that you own you can [add them to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/) and claim those commits. But I don't think they are (certainly the one `@Sahands-MBP.lan` doesn't look right).

I suggest

1. Adding any email addresses you plan on using to your GitHub profile.
2. Setting your email address properly on those two machines, e.g. via

   ```
   git config --global user.email "sahandz@hotmail.com"
   ```

   This will enable GitHub to associate new commits with your account.
3. [Adding a `.mailmap` file to map the wrong email addresses to the correct email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10253883/354577).

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Is there any way to get credit for the commits that were made with the faulty email addresses? Is that what your option 3 is for?

Comment: @Sahand, I've seen people say that 3 works on GitHub. I've also seen them say it doesn't. The surefire way would be to [rewrite those commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/354577) and push to GitHub using `--force-with-lease`. In my opinion that's a big hammer for a tiny nail (I'd just leave the commits as-is and accept that the author information is wrong), but you may disagree. Please bear in mind that [rewriting history has major implications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491001/354577), especially if you're working with others. Please do your research if you go down that path.

Comment: Right, probably too big a job for the reward. Lesson learned. I'll try your 1,2,3 :)

Comment: One more question, how did you find those email addresses? I've looked around the github website and I can't find them myself.

Comment: On GitHub, if an email address matches an account, the committer's name will be linked to their account, e.g. here: https://github.com/Sahand1993/CraigslistPrice/commits/master. I noticed that most of your commits weren't linked, which is what led me to the email mismatch. I cloned the repository and the used `git log` to look at the commit data locally.